# Destroying Date object

Tags: java, android, multithreading, date, java-threads

I need some advice on this code:

```
Thread myClock = new Thread() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      while (!isInterrupted()) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            Date dt = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat myClockDate = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy");
            SimpleDateFormat myClockTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
            myClock_date.setText("Date:  " + myClockDate.format(dt));
            myClock_time.setText("Time:  " + (myClockTime.format(dt)).replace(".", ""));
          }
        });
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

    }
  }
};
```

It works well but when the thread is running, the memory monitor shows a consistent rise and fall in usage. When it's not running, the monitor flat-lines.

I'm wondering if it's the continuous creation of the date object that's causing this? Does it need to be destroyed or released?

PS: The GPU monitor has been disabled.

Comment: do not create any of the objects in the "while".

Comment: Hi Kerim. So, what should remain in the WHILE loop? It's required, right?

Comment: Why do you worry? I don’t think I would.

Comment: @OleV.V. Are the memory fluctuations normal, or acceptable? Shouldn't the memory usage be stable?

Comment: I don’t see a straightforward way to avoid creating a `Date` in each iteration, @KerimFIRAT. The two `SimpleDateFormat` objects could be created once before the loop, of course.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes; placing the two date format objects outside the loop makes a big difference, But there's still the slow (much slower now) climb in memory usage. So, hopefully the garbage collector's going to handle that. This is not a memory leak, right?

Comment: No, it’s not. While I hesitate to do so generally, I think your code is simple enough that I can say there is no memory leak in it. A memory leak would be if the garbage collector was unable to collect the objects and reclaim the space.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153555/discussion-between-ole-v-v-and-isofia).

Comment: By the way, the troublesome legacy date-time classes you are using are *not* thread-safe. Use their replacement, the thread-safe [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes instead.

Answer (score 3):

Every second your code creates a Runnable, a Date, and two DateFormat objects. Also the string operations may create some objects. Once the Runnable finishes those get cut loose (nothing outside the Runnable has a reference to any of them) and are eligible for garbage collection. You don't need to do anything further to release their memory. you should see memory usage return to the same level after each of these Runnables completes.

Garbage collection is not immediate. As long as you don't see an ongoing upward trend it's ok.

Comment: Hi Nathan. Actually, it hits some limit and drops again - but not on the completion of every runnable (every second). That's alright?

Comment: Sounds completely normal to me, @iSofia. Probably the garbage collector doesn’t run every second. It should run whenever the memory is needed, though. Only when it does, does the memory consumption drop.